# Query Result is correct but when use execute scalar function system return 0

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

```
ConnectString.connectStr()
con.Open()
Try
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandText = ("select COUNT(userid) from login where userid='" & UserNametxt.Text & "'")
    Dim userName As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
    If userName <> 0 Then
        cmd.CommandText = ("select COUNT(password) from login where userid='" & passwordtxt.Text & "'")
        Dim password As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        If password <> 0 Then
            UserMenu.Show()
        Else
            MsgBox("Password is wrong")
        End If
    Else
```

Comment: You have two `cmd.ExecuteScalar()` in the code. Which one is returning 0 for you?

Comment: I guess you do not need to perform `WHERE` by `userid`? I the first case instead of used id you are passing user name, and in the other, you are passing password?

Comment: UserName is not return 1 , Db have already existing data

Comment: One field can only have one value. You are checking in your first query `userid='" & UserNametxt.Text & "'"` and in the second query `userid='" & passwordtxt.Text & "'")`. Minimum one of the queries returns 0. BTW: please try to use parameters in your queries to avoid SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Query result of normal Query and Function could not be different for your case. But there should be a problem in your function.
Please correct your code with below one.

```
CREATE FUNCTION test_example (@userid BIGINT)
RETURNS BIGINT
BEGIN
    RETURN (select COUNT(userid) from login where userid = @userid)
END
```

Comment: how to call from that function in vb.net? and how to pass user_id  from screen

Comment: Same as SQL Query : select test_example (in_param)

Answer (score 0):

Keep your connection local and don't open it until the last minute.

The Using blocks ensure that your database objects will be closed and disposed even if there is an error.

Always use parameters when calling the database. Otherwise you risk Sql Injection. Also it prevents errors passing the data and may speed up the query.

Why hit the database twice? Just ask you question in one query with an And in the Where clause. Don't let the user know if the username or password is incorrect. Remember, you are trying to prevent unauthorized access. Just say that the login failed.

I moved the declaration of CountUser above the Using block so it can be seen below the Using block. We don't want to display the MessageBox while the connection is open. There is no telling when the user would respond to the message and the connection would be open waiting.

In a real application you would never store passwords as plain text.

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim CountUser As Integer
    'Pass the connection string directly to the constructor of the connection.
    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string")
        'Pass the command text and the connection directly to the constructor of the command
        Using cmd As New SqlCommand("select COUNT(userid) from login where userid = @UserID And password = @password;", cn)
            'I am guessing on the SqlDbType. Check the database for the actual type.
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = UserNametxt.Text
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passwordtxt.Text
            cn.Open()
            CountUser = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar())
        End Using
    End Using
    If CountUser <> 1 Then
        MessageBox.Show("Login Failed")
    Else
        'Send them into the progam
    End If
End Sub
```